# why concatenate strings is so ultra slow?

Tags: objective-c, performance, nsstring

I am using the NSXMLParser to parse a .xml file into my project. So far i have no problem. in my .xml is an ImageURL wich look like this: "www.fooo.com/image.jpg" to show this image I need to 


`urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];`


This line is very slow. I use it in a loop to edit every single value. 
eg.

```
for (NSDictionary *locationDetails in parser.items)
{
    NSString *urlString = locationDetails[@"imageURL"];
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlString];
    NSURL *storeImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"img %@", urlString);
}
```

The loadtime of my app was aprox 3 seconds. after this lane it grows to 20 seconds! Is there a way to do the same but faster??

Comment: First: remove `NSLog` if you do performance measurements. Printing stuff is VERY expensiv. Second: `stringByAppendingString` should be slightly faster than `stringWithFormat`. For more performance gain you might have to use pure c instead of objective-c. Or just add the `http://` part when you need it. Also `NSURL initWithScheme:host:path:` might be usefull.

Comment: okay I will try it and the NSLog is only for testing ;)

Comment: I tried this `NSString *urlString = [KHTTP stringByAppendingString:stringAppending];` but it is still slow

Comment: How often is this executed in a loop? I mean - how many instances do you have? And do you really need to do all that during app loading?

Comment: Interested to know how many items are being processed as 20 seconds means many millions or some other problem... You can (should) also run this processing on a background task.

Comment: there are about 500 loops. the whole procedure without the `stringWithFormat` line is finished after 3 seconds but with the line: every single loop need about 7 times longer

Comment: Okay i stopped the time: 39 seconds! This is insane

Comment: Have you tried to run the time profiler in Instruments? It definitely sounds like the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you actually doing anything (besides logging) with the URLs you create? If yes the bottleneck might be there instead. If not you might as well leave out the whole loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to minimize the number of obj-c messages sent and temporary objects created and destroyed. To that end, try something like:

`[NSURL initWitScheme:@"http" host:nil path:locationDetails[@"imageURL"]];`